# Outlook Web Addin change icon programmatically

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I developped a simple Oultook Web Addin and I would need to change my icon when my ribbon button has been clicked (A javascript function is called which is processing my job and I would need to change icon color from blue to green).

My manifest.xml is getting the following elements:

```
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgCompose">
<Label resid="FunctionButton.Label"/>
<Supertip>
   <Title resid="FunctionButton.Title"/>
   <Description resid="FunctionButton.Tooltip"/>
</Supertip>
<Icon>
   <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16_blue"/>
   <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32_blue"/>
   <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80_blue"/>
</Icon>
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
   <FunctionName>compose</FunctionName>
</Action>
</Control>
```

and I declared the following Resources:

```
<Resources>
  <bt:Images>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16_blue" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms16-blue.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32_blue" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms32-blue.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80_blue" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms80-blue.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16_green" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms16-green.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32_green" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms32-green.png"/>
    <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80_green" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/ms80-green.png"/>
  </bt:Images>
  ....
```

I would need, from a Javascript function to change manifest.xml the resid of my icons to display:

```
<Icon>
  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16_green"/>
  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32_green"/>
  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80_green"/>
</Icon>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible.

Comment: ok...bad news !

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.